# A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware' could not be located

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Please see the following link for instructions on how to ask for help on here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

If this is the error you're getting it might be what I was hitting.
I was passing my extension a parameter that defaulted to null which was then being passed to UseMiddleware, e.g:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder, string myParam = null)
{
    return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>(myParam);
}
```

It turns out that passing this null parameter does work so you'll want to change it to something non-null

```
...myParam = "")
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into the same issue and it can be tricky to figure this one out.

Comment: i can't believe how misleading this error message is